# Airflow determine Ephemeral storage used by a dag

Tags: kubernetes, memory, airflow, ephemeral-storage, google-cloud-composer-2

I am working on airflow migration to cloud composer task.
The dags use Kubernetespodoperator to spin up a container and execute spark jobs.

In CC2, as the cluster is in autopilot mode, the pods get evicted due to ephemeral storage 1Gib default in autopilot mode.

My question is is there a way to find out, from the existing airflow, how much ephemeral storage a dag requires?
I need this value to be set in limit_resources of the dag operator.

Similarly can i find the memory used by this particular dag from airflow 2?

Comment: In general, you should avoid using Compute and Storage resources from Airflow's infrastructure in your Airflow Tasks. The goal of Airflow is to delegate its load to another infrastructure.

Comment: @vdolez meaning like we should spin up a separate kubernetes cluster to run a our jobs?

Comment: Yeah, if you're using GCP, maybe Dataproc is the correct infrastructure for you to migrate your Spark jobs. Airflow is just supposed to schedule your pipeline's start.